# Can I uninstall Java ambiguos version

Tags: windows, java, version

Can I uninstall Java Update 8 131 if I also have Java Update 8 131 (64-bit)? It looks like waste of space. I'am running Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: See programs list from control panel. You may see both of them.

Comment: I did that, that's how I know I have both installed

Comment: 32-bit and 64-big installations of Java are seperate

Comment: I know that @Ramhound but I don't know if I can uninstall 32 bit version if I have 64-bit also installed

Comment: They are separate.  If they are separate you can have both installed.  You can also if you want have Java 6, Java 7, and Java 8 installed on your system

Comment: so 32-bit java programs can't run on 64-bit java platform?

Comment: I am saying you can have both installed.  You have all 6 installations (per my other example) if you wanted.  The installations are separate.  A 32-bit Java application requires a 32-bit version of Java to be installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* uninstall Java Update 8 131 32bit, if you wish. Most Java apps will happily run with 64bit.

That said, it's possible an app you have on your machine requires one of the features only provided by 32bit Java, and thus will break if you remove it.

Try it, as it's simple enough to reinstall from Java.com